# Вывод графиков на python

Tags: python, график

Здравствуйте.
Появилась задача вывести несколько графиков.
Например, есть функция y = f(x), и мне надо вывести график с точки x1 до x2 с шагом delta.
Можно ли сделать что-либо подобное на python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на [CairoPlot](http://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/).

> CairoPlot является API, написанным на языке Python использующим PyCairo для построения 6 видов графиков.

Обычный график функции выводится вызовом `function_plot`.

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!